# download csv file contains double quotes in php-codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I have done a code for downloading template (with sample data)using codeigniter.but when heading or cell value contain space,the downloaded csv file contains double quotes.Here is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=teacher_template.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('first name','middlename'));
fputcsv($output, array('Johnthomas ','xx yy'));
```

when i downloaded csv file,it came like this:

```
"first name",middlename
Johnthomas,"xx yy"
```

Icannot change my heading and cell value please help

Comment: i just check your code its working fine in linux. Plz specify your problem

Comment: Yes code is working,but when heading contains space,it will come within double quotes in downloaded csv,same as first row sample data.

Comment: i dont want double quotes in downloaded csv file.

Comment: Works for me and it HAS TO wrap a text that contains a space in double quotes, but when you load this output DIRECTLY into Excel it works all that out automatically

Comment: Sir these csv file i want it for inserting into database.if double quotes will be there,it wont insert into db

Comment: A CSV file ___should___ wrap strings in quotes when they contain characters like spaces (or your delimiter): how are you loading the data into a database in a way that can't recognise valid double quotes in a CSV file correctly

Comment: it's working fine, can u share which platform i.e. linux, windows, etc and version of php u using?

Comment: If it won't insert the values in de database when they're wrapped in quotes, how is that software gonna handle values that have a comma in it??

Answer (score 0):

```
fputcsv($output, array('first name','middlename','',chr(0)));
fputcsv($output, array('Johnthomas ','xx yy',',',chr(0)));
```

It will help you